# Is it possible to run sshd as a normal user?

Tags: ssh

I'm aiming to start up a second `sshd` instance on a non-privileged port (e.g. 2222) with my own configuration file.

Obviously, the `sshd` process can't `setuid` so logging in as users other than the one who is running the `sshd` daemon is clearly impossible.

However, is it possible to have a working `sshd` daemon that will work for the currently running user? For my use case, this would be fine.

I tried booting up an `sshd` instance with my own config file and host key and the `sshd` process starts up (no complaints about not being root, like some commands), however when I try to connect to that port, the `sshd` process dies.

```
$ /usr/sbin/sshd -dD -h .ssh/id_rsa -p 2222 
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_5.6p1
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: private host key: #0 type 1 RSA
debug1: setgroups() failed: Operation not permitted
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-dD'
debug1: rexec_argv[2]='-h'
debug1: rexec_argv[3]='.ssh/id_rsa'
debug1: rexec_argv[4]='-p'
debug1: rexec_argv[5]='2222'
debug1: Bind to port 2222 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 2222.
debug1: Bind to port 2222 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 2222.
debug1: fd 6 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug1: rexec start in 6 out 6 newsock 6 pipe -1 sock 9
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 5, 5
Connection from ::1 port 57670
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_5.6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.6 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.6
debug1: list_hostkey_types: 
No supported key exchange algorithms
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: audit_event: unhandled event 12
```

The `debug1: setgroups() failed: Operation not permitted` line obviously sticks out, but it doesn't die until it tries to accept a connection.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Start the process with `sshd -f ~/.ssh/sshd_config` where `~/.ssh/sshd_config` is a new file you created. Among other options (such as a different host key, different port, etc) you need to add the line `UsePrivilegeSeparation no`. This will prevent the `sshd` process from trying to do any `setuid` or `setgid` calls and allow it to continue running as your user and accept connections as your user.

(This link confirms it is the correct way: http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2008-04/msg00363.html )

Comment: You also need to disable PAM by setting `UsePam` to `no`.

Comment: @bjeanes does it work for you? can you share your sshd_config file? it complain "Set" is not a valid command for me when i try on ubuntu.

Comment: @jojo I don't run this configuration so I have no file to share. You're going to have to start with a known working file and adjust to your needs.

Comment: The disabling PAM thing is only for specific cases. Works for me on Fedora without messing with the pam setting. See the linked email message in the answer for some more ideas what else needs to be changed to get all things nice. I'll update soon my notes how I made it work for docker: https://hub.docker.com/r/aosqe/ssh-git-server/ (please allow a couple of days before reading it)

Comment: Deprecated option UsePrivilegeSeparation

Answer (score 15):

Here is a userland bash script based on the Bo Jeanes' answer that :

- Creates a working dir in home
- Generates server keys in the working dir
- Generates a basic config file with pid file located in the working dir
- launches an SSH daemon

```bash
mkdir ${HOME}/custom_ssh
ssh-keygen -f ${HOME}/custom_ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key -N '' -t rsa
ssh-keygen -f ${HOME}/custom_ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key -N '' -t dsa

cat << EOF > ${HOME}/custom_ssh/sshd_config
Port 2222
HostKey ${HOME}/custom_ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey ${HOME}/custom_ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server
PidFile ${HOME}/custom_ssh/sshd.pid
EOF

/usr/bin/sshd -f ${HOME}/custom_ssh/sshd_config
echo "----- Process ID : ${HOME}/custom_ssh/sshd.pid -------"
```

- OpenSSH_7.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018
- pam auth (tested with same local & remote user)

Comment: I still see: "debug1: setgroups() failed: Operation not permitted"

Comment: Good solution, but you should make commands look better. Ugly.

Comment: Yes, just changing the PidFile path was sufficient for me... Duh!...

Comment: @dotbit: I get this error as well, but it doesn't prevent sshd to work correctly in user-mode

Comment: I had to set UsePAM to no in Ubuntu as it was having an issue with access message of the day

Comment: From `man sshd_config`:   If UsePAM is enabled, you will not be able to run sshd(8) as a non-root user.   The default is no.  For Debian openssh-server package, the default for `UsePAM` is `yes`

Answer (score 14):

As an update to this thread, OpenSSH in version 7.5 deprecated the UsePrivilegeSeparation option, making it impossible to disable privilege separation. It appears that running SSHD as a user is now impossible.

See https://www.openssh.com/releasenotes.html

Comment: Depending on the server configuration, this may not be the case. I have no problem running sshd as a normal user while indicating "UsePrivilegeSeparation yes" or "UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox" in my sshd config file.

Comment: Well I haven't tried it yet, but I think this is "fixed" now: "sshd(8): when started without root privileges, don't require the privilege separation user or path to exist. Makes running the regression tests easier without touching the filesystem."

Comment: OpenSSH 7.5 was released on 2017-03-20.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming what @magiclantern noted [above](https://serverfault.com/a/861842/74476) and assuming you don't want to patch `sshd` will something like [Dropbear](https://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/dropbear.html) work for you?   It is used in many embedded devices that want an ssh server with smaller footprint (and fewer features/configs).

Comment: dropbear -E -F -R -w -g -a -p 2222 -P ./dbearPID
# does the trick

Comment: `dropbearkey -t rsa -f ./dropbear_rsa_host_key`  and then `dropbear -E -F -w -g -a -p 2222 -P ./dbearPID -r ./dropbear_rsa_host_key`

Answer (score 3):

I have checked in detail the possibility of running sshd service as a normal user.
Detail of the version of the program:

> sshd version OpenSSH_7.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2k

Finally after solving many errors, I reached to a point that SSHD aborted with the following error:

> Attempt to write login records by non-root user (aborting)

I checked the source code to see whether it is possible to solve the issue without changing the source code. See the code [here](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/loginrec.c). Some part of the code causing abortion of the program:

```
#ifndef HAVE_CYGWIN
    if (geteuid() != 0) {
        logit("Attempt to write login records by non-root user (aborting)");
        return (1);
    }
#endif
```

It checks the user privilege by `(geteuid() != 0)` and here causes the problem.

Comment: I ran into this error as well, but it happens only with debug output activated. Without debug output there's no error, I can run sshd in user-mode just fine.

Comment: Hi @CharlesB, I'm having trouble* setting up a rootless sshd server on alpine docker container. Would you be kind enough to share contents of your `sshd_config` file?

*trouble = even though providing correct password, it always keeps rejecting with _Permission denied, please try again._.

Comment: @Lukas Sorry this was long ago I don't have this setup anymore

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu users, the answer above (https://serverfault.com/a/946877/994202) should be :

```bash
mkdir ${HOME}/custom_ssh
ssh-keygen -f ${HOME}/custom_ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key -N '' -t rsa
ssh-keygen -f ${HOME}/custom_ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key -N '' -t dsa


cat << EOF > ${HOME}/custom_ssh/sshd_config
Port 6666
HostKey ${HOME}/custom_ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey ${HOME}/custom_ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
PidFile ${HOME}/custom_ssh/sshd.pid
EOF

/usr/sbin/sshd -f ${HOME}/custom_ssh/sshd_config
```

Then type `ssh -p 6666 your_not_root_user_name@your_ip` in local shell.